# Problem using signerMustLoginToSign with embeeded signing and rest api

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using embedded signing with rest api and signerMustLoginToSign=true configuration to force users to login before sign.

I realised that just docusign account owner is abble to sign. If I try to sign with other users I get the message:

Authentication Error
The login information provided does not match the account for this envelope. Please try again and login with the same email address where you received this envelope.

I'm doing a POST to /evelopes with data:

```
    *{
       "emailSubject":"Document Signing",
       "documents":[
          {
             "documentId":192691,
             "name":"mydoc.docx",
             "fileExtension":"docx",
             "documentBase64":"base64"
          }
       ],
       "recipients":{
          "signers":[
             {
                "roleName":"HR",
                "name":"User 1",
                "email":"user1@user.com",
                "recipientId":"845a9b97-b31f-4823-842e-91c1e963eca2",
                "routingOrder":null,
                "clientUserId":null,
                "userId":null,
                "tabs":{
                   "signHereTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#HR",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "dateSignedTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#todaydate",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "textTabs":[

                   ],
                   "fullNameTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#HiredFullName",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "titleTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#HiredTitle",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "roleName":"CR",
                "name":"User 2",
                "email":"user2@user.com",
                "recipientId":"9d1f5d02-8006-452c-918d-ddeb07fa799f",
                "routingOrder":null,
                "clientUserId":null,
                "userId":null,
                "tabs":{
                   "signHereTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#CR",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "dateSignedTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#todaydate",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "textTabs":[

                   ],
                   "fullNameTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#ContractorFullName",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ],
                   "titleTabs":[
                      {
                         "anchorString":"#ContractorTitle",
                         "anchorXOffset":0,
                         "anchorYOffset":0,
                         "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                         "anchorUnits":"inches",
                         "locked":true
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       "status":"sent",
       "sentDate":{
          "year":2020,
          "dayOfYear":88,
          "dayOfMonth":28,
          "dayOfWeek":6,
          "era":1,
          "hourOfDay":11,
          "centuryOfEra":20,
          "weekyear":2020,
          "minuteOfHour":54,
          "yearOfCentury":20,
          "yearOfEra":2020,
          "minuteOfDay":714,
          "monthOfYear":3,
          "millisOfSecond":189,
          "secondOfMinute":49,
          "millisOfDay":42889189,
          "secondOfDay":42889,
          "weekOfWeekyear":13,
          "millis":1585407289189,
          "zone":{
             "fixed":false,
             "uncachedZone":{
                "cachable":true,
                "fixed":false,
                "id":"America/Sao_Paulo"
             },
             "id":"America/Sao_Paulo"
          },
          "chronology":{
             "zone":{
                "fixed":false,
                "uncachedZone":{
                   "cachable":true,
                   "fixed":false,
                   "id":"America/Sao_Paulo"
                },
                "id":"America/Sao_Paulo"
             }
          },
          "equalNow":false,
          "afterNow":false,
          "beforeNow":true
       },
       "completeDate":null
    }*
```

Comment: Please also share the code you're using for the embedded signing

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you generate the embedded signing but I can answer what the error means.
This error comes from an API call that is made in a different account that does not match the envelope. I suspect you're trying to login with a different account, not just a different user of the same account. This login you're doing as part of embedded signing, should not have this issue if the request was made correctly.

Edit: please ensure `clientUserId` is not null or empty. this value is used to identify the embedded sending application for a specific recipient.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the respose. Bellow I'm show the request for signing URL:

Endpoint - /views/recipient 
Data: 

<pre>
"userName": "User",
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "recipientId": "9b6953e0-1215-4ab1-a807-c99a02df90cb",
    "clientUserId": null,
    "userId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx",
    "authenticationMethod": "email",
    "returnUrl": "http://localhost:8080/signed"
</pre>

If a sign using the link on the e-mail sent by docusign works fine, but if a sign using the link generared by the API I get the issue reported.

Comment: clientUserId should not be null. Can you try to put a value in there? that value is a unique ID for your integration and a specific recipient.